# How much resources a mysql event use?

Tags: mysql, events

Im working on a browser game and I write 7 mysql events for each player.
5 of events update a table row every 5 secs.
And two of them update 2 other tables every sec.
I have a linux vps that its ram is 512 M and cpu has 1 core.
How many online players can support this VPS.
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minimum system requirement for mysql for windows (86 and 64) is 800 mb ram and 500 mb hard disk space

Read this article to get some further knowledge.

[dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-monitor/3.0/en/system-prereqs-reference.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-monitor/3.0/en/system-prereqs-reference.html)

Comment: But I want to know that mysql events use more cpu and ram? or has no effect?

Comment: Bro its depends by your pc. If you can run this project in someone else pc and see. You will find answer by own.. thnk you

Comment: Can u say Approximately how much cpu and ram use mysql event? And is it wise to use more than 1000 events in one vps for a game?

Comment: I cant exactly tell number. Go through this.  www.tocker.ca/2014/03/10/configuring-mysql-to-use-minimal-memory.html

Comment: But here isnt no sign of event scheduler!!! Is there any page that shows any number about event scheduler memory and cpu usage? And thank u for your answers and vote up :X

Comment: Will tell you simply get few knowledge. Try this on another machine(RAM 1GB o +). If its work perfectly it means your ram is not enugh. As a web developer if you use 1GB RAM it will good for you to easy up your works. And i think its dificlt to tl a number for that friend. Because its belongs to your coding.

Comment: Aha. Thank u very much friend.